# Powershell - How to filter an attachment before download

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am using a PowerShell script to download attachment from an email which has multiple attachment.

If I use below statement it will download all the attachments.

```
# Find Unread mail messages
$UnreadMessages = $Inbox.Items | where-object {$_.Unread -and $_.SenderEmailAddress -imatch "usa"}
```

I want to download only a specific attachment using below statement but it gives nothing.

```
# Find Unread mail messages
$UnreadMessages = $Inbox.Items | where-object {$_.Unread -and $_.SenderEmailAddress -imatch "usa" -and $_.Attachments -imatch "Backlog"}
```

Please help me correct this statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code will cause all Inbox messages to be downloaded and processed by your script. This is like a SELECT statement in SQL without a WHERE clause - as bad as it gets performance wise.

Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find) - let the server/message store do the work. For your first query, use

```
@SQL=("urn:schemas:httpmail:read" = 0) AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F" like '%usa%')
```

For the second query, OOM won't let you search on the attachment name even though Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) exposes that functionality (create `RES_SUBRESTRICTION` on `PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS` and specify `PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME` as the search property). You can of course use only your first query and loop over the query matches, for each entry looping through each `Attachment` object in the `MailItem.Attachments` collection - far from ideal, but still better than no restriction at all. 
If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author - it is an Extended MAPI wrapper and can be used from any language) is an option, it allows to use `Attachments` in queries. Something like the following (off the top of my head, VBA):

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
set restrItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(" (UnRead = 'true') AND (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F"" like '%usa%') AND (Attachments LIKE '%Backlog%')")
for each item in restrItems
  Debug.Print item.Subject
next
```